# Why my data loop multiple times when I created dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

The first step starts with getting the data from mysql. Then, I will do the spellchecker with the dictionary that I have created. Lastly, insert the output in mysql. The problem is I got the output looping for multiple time.Hope u can help me

My code:

**app.py**

```
from dic import dikk

cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE id=%s", [id])

data = cur.fetchall()


for row in data:


    for k, v in dikk.items():
        t = re.compile(re.escape(k), re.IGNORECASE)
        row['a'] = t.sub(v, row['a'])
        print(row['a'])



        mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO table2 (a) VALUES (%s)"""
        records_to_insert =[(row['a'])]

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        cur.execute(mySql_insert_query, records_to_insert)

       # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()
```

**dic.py**

```
dikk={'speling':'spelling','writen':'written','Jhon':'John'}
```

**Output that I got:**

```
it is not Jhon
it is not Jhon
it is not John
```

**My desired output:**

```
it is not John
```

Comment: What is `row['g']`? You're only selecting `a`.

Comment: Where do you execute the `INSERT` query?

Comment: Ohh..sorry...I already edited it....

Comment: How is `row['a']` working at all? `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, not a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over a dictionary with 3 key value pairs, and calling `print` and `insert` for each loop, causing it to trigger 3 times.

If you move your calls to `insert` and `print` to outside of the loop, you will have one return per element.

```
dikk={'speling':'spelling','writen':'written','Jhon':'John'}

data = [('it is not Jhon',), ('you spell it speling',), ('writen is the way',)]

for idx, value in enumerate(data):
    for word in value[0].split(" "):
        if word in dikk.keys():
            data[idx] = data[idx][0].replace(word, dikk[word])

    # Insert can go here    
for row in data:
    print(row)
    # Or insert can go here

#it is not John
#you spell it spelling
#written is the way
```

You can add your `insert` into each row in `data`, or you can insert it separately later by looping over your `data` list again.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the query after each spelling correction, so you insert all the intermediate results. You should only do it once after *all* the corrections.

And you can call `mysql.connection.commit()` only once after processing all the rows, it doesn't need to be in the loop.

`row['a']` should be `row[0]` since `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, not dictionaries.

```
for row in data:
    for k, v in dikk.items():
        t = re.compile(re.escape(k), re.IGNORECASE)
        row[0] = t.sub(v, row[0])
    print(row[0])
    mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO table2 (a) VALUES (%s)"""
    cur.execute(mySql_insert_query, (row[0],))
mysql.connection.commit()
```

It's also possible to do all the replacements with a single call to `re.sub()`, rather than a loop. Convert all the keys to a regexp like `key1|key2|key3|...`, and use a function to get the replacement from the dictionary.

```
t = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(k) for k in dikk))
row['a'] = t.sub(lambda m: dikk[m.group(0)], row['a']
```

Comment: yeah...actually I already done the execute query...But, I forgot to write here...sorry2

Comment: Will this not return a `TypeError`?  `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples and `row` would be iterating over the tuples where `row['a']` has been called?

Comment: @PacketLoss If the code in the question works, it must be getting a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Must be, however everywhere i have checked shows `fetchall()` [returning a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14861480/7942856).